# Ошибка при INSERT данных в MySQL

Tags: mysql, mariadb, insert

Работаем с MacOS и SQL `MariaDB` (если это важно)
Создал базу данных `gregs_list` и не заполненную таблицу `my_contacts`

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| last_name  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| email      | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| birthday   | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| profession | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| location   | varchar(50)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| status     | varchar(20)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| interests  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

После захода в MySQL и включении базы, не удается выполнить вот эту команду:

```
INSERT INTO my_contacts
(last_name, first_name, email, gender, birthday,
profession, location, status, interests)
VALUES
(‘Anderson’, ‘Jillian’, ‘j_anderson@mail.com’, ‘W’,
‘1980-01-01’, ‘Writer’, ‘Palo-Alto CA’, ‘Not-married’,
‘Kayak, Terrarium’);
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@mail.com’, ‘W’,
‘1980-01-01’, ‘Writer’, ‘Palo-Alto CA’, ‘No' at line 5
```

Помогите плз найти причину\ошибку.

UPD: убрал лишнее поле и перенабрал команду. Теперь ошибка

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
>   syntax to use near '@mail.com’, ‘W’, ‘1980-01-01’, ‘Writer’,
>   ‘Palo-Alto CA’, ‘No' at line 5

Comment: поле `seeking` есть в таблице?

Comment: и проверьте кавычки у вас одинаковые везде? ` ‘  ' `

Comment: убрал seeking и перенабрал вручную всю команду. Теперь ошибка. ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@mail.com’, ‘W’,
‘1980-01-01’, ‘Writer’, ‘Palo-Alto CA’, ‘No' at line 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ошибка при INSERT данных в MySQL

При условии, что у вас в таблице присутствуют все поля, которые вы вносите.

Все кавычки должны быть `'`.

Вот так:

```
INSERT INTO my_contacts 
(last_name, first_name, email, gender, birthday,
profession, location, status, interests, seeking)
VALUES
('Anderson', 'Jillian', 'jill_anderson@mail.com', 
'W', '1980-05-09', 'Writer',  'Palo-Alto, CA', 'Not married',
'Kayak, terrarium', 'Friends');
```

---

**UPD:**

В английской версии [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark), есть чёткое определение кавычек:

- `'...' и "..."` - более известны как нейтральные, вертикальные, прямые или *ASCII* ковычки, одинаковые с обоих левой и правой сторон.
- `‘...’ и “...”` - более известные как типографские, волнистые/курчавые или умные кавычки.

---

В случае с вашим примером у вас микс из тех и других, а должны быть, только первые (*ASCII*).

Comment: Ваш код сработал, благодарю! Но я все-равно не нахожу в нем отличие от моего. (кроме отсутствия seeking, что я потом подкорректировал) Вас не затруднит 'пальцем показать' где была ошибка?

Comment: @MR `‘Jillian’` !== `'Jillian'`  [Кавычки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark)